# Each component of $X$ is second-countable

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

This problem relates paracompactness to connected components in a space $X$, which I find it fairly hard to do. Hope some one can help me solve this or give me some useful hints. Thanks.

> > If $X$ is a Hausdorff space that is locally compact and paracompact, then each component of $X$ is second-countable

Comment: The first thought that comes to mind is that components are closed, and both local compactness and paracompactness are weakly hereditary, so the problem reduces to proving that a *connected*, paracompact, locally compact Hausdorff space is second-countable.

Comment: This is problem 10, section 41 of the Topology text by Munkres. It shows up in the following [errata](http://www.math.toronto.edu/drorbn/classes/0405/Topology/etc/MunkresErrata.html)--look at the entry "261; 7". The suggestion is that paracompact should be replaced with metrizable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is *false*. According to [Spacebook](http://austinmohr.com/home/?page_id=146), the following are compact (hence paracompact and locally compact), connected Hausdorff spaces that are not second-countable:

- Alexandroff Square
- Helly Space
- Lexicographic Ordering on the Unit Square
- The Extended Long Line
- Uncountable Cartesian Product of Unit Interval

The last seems easiest to deal with. Let $I=[0,1]$ and let $X=I^S$, where $S$ is uncountable. Then $X$ is compact because it is a product of compact spaces, connected because it is a product of connected spaces, and Hausdorff because it is a product of Hausdorff spaces. Suppose $\mathcal B$ is a countable basis of $X$. Then because a countable union of finite sets is countable, there is some $i\in S$ such that every element of $\mathcal B$ has a basic (in the sense of the usual basis for the product topology) subset whose $i$th projection is $I$, contradicting the claim that $\mathcal B$ is a basis.

Comment: I know nothing about any topological space you list above (except the last one). But thanks so much for telling me that this problem is wrong. I will try to check your counter-examples...

Comment: @leducquang: The lexicographic ordering on the unit square is easy to understand, but I haven't yet tried proving that it has the necessary properties. I don't think the extended long line is too terrible either. The others I know nothing about.

Comment: Oh, lexicographic ordering square, is it the $I_{0}^{2}$ space in dictionary order?

Comment: And as Karl Kronenfeld said, can we prove this problem if we replace "paracompact" by "metrizable"?

Comment: Yes, lexicographic ordery is what the dictionary uses. If you want metrizable, I suggest asking a new question and linking it from and to here.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning Munkres, problem 41-10.  Take any 
uncountable Cartesian product of [0,1]; it is compact + Hausdorff 
as noted (by Kelley pp. 92,143).  Hence, paracompact.
It is connected by Kelley, problem 3.O; and, non-second countable 
by Kelley problem 3.M.  Since second-countable implies 
first-countable, non-second countability also follows from 
Kelley p.92 (theorem 6).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, *paracompact* should be replaced by *metrizable*. Below is how you prove it when the exercise itself has been corrected. All theorems are quoted from Munkres.

First, every metrizable space is paracompact by Theorem 41.4. So you can follow the hint given in the book.

> If $X_0$ is a component of $X$, then $X_0$ is locally compact and paracompact. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a locally finite covering of $X_0$ by sets open in $X_0$ that have compact closures.

You can find such a covering $\mathcal{C}$ by covering $X_0$ by a collection of open sets each of which is inside a compact subspace by local compactness, and then refine them by paracompactness.

> Let $U_1$ be a nonempty element of $\mathcal{C}$, and in general let $U_n$ be the union of all elements of $\mathcal{C}$ that intersect $\overline{U}_{n−1}$. Show $\overline{U}_n$ is compact, and the sets $U_n$ cover $X_0$.

By construction, $\overline{U}_1$ is compact. Each $x \in \overline{U}_1$ has a neighborhood that intersects a finite number of members of $\mathcal{C}$. By compactness, $\overline{U}_1$ can be covered by a finite number of such neighborhoods. Therefore $\overline{U}_1$ intersects only a finite number of members of $\mathcal{C}$. Thus $\overline{U}_2$ is compact because it is a union of a finite number of compact sets. (We are also using Lemma 39.1, which says $\overline{\cup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} A} = \cup_{A \in \mathcal{A}} \bar{A})$ if $\mathcal{A}$ is a locally finite collection of subsets of $X$.)

So by induction $\overline{U}_n$ is compact.

$\cup_n U_n$ is obviously open. It is also closed because if $x \in \overline{\cup_n U_n}$, every neighborhood must intersect $\overline{\cup_n U_n} = \cup_n \overline{U_n}$. In particular, we take a member of $\mathcal{C}$ that covers $x$ as the neighborhood. It must intersect $\overline{U_n}$ for some $n$. Therefore $x \in U_{n+1} \subset \cup_n U_n$.

Since $X_0$ is connected, $\cup_n U_n = X_0$.

The rest is essentially the same proof showing that every compact metrizable space $X$ has a countable basis. (Exercise 4 of §30.)